# Meteor: server-side db insert delays

Tags: meteor

Interesting issue: I've got a MongoDb collection that I'm updating server side, with Meteor client-side hooks into the same collection. I'm noticing ~10 second delays for a mongo-cursor (server side) inserted record to make its way down to the clients.

Here's the rub: If I do the same insert via the Meteor Client (via a Chrome console) the client and all others attached update with sub-second response times.

There's a very large disparity between the server-side insert into Mongo vs. the Client side - somehow the client side inserts are propagated through and pushed out to the other clients *much* more quickly than if I manually insert documents via the MongoDb shell.

Any ideas on this? I'm sure I'm missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meteor mongo driver *polls for changes in Mongo every 10 seconds* to ensure that data that's written into it from outside Meteor makes its way down to the client. Here's the relevant [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js#L592):

```
  // every once and a while, poll even if we don't think we're dirty,
  // for eventual consistency with database writes from outside the
  // Meteor universe
  var intervalHandle = Meteor.setInterval(
    _.bind(self._ensurePollIsScheduled, self), 10 * 1000 /* 10 seconds */);
    self._stopCallbacks.push(function () {
    Meteor.clearInterval(intervalHandle);
  });
```

This behavior **is likely to change** [per Matt Debergalis, one of the core devs](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/F3Ctw_EhE24/P-nlKrFpURAJ):

> This polling is so that Meteor will notice DB changes that didn't come through the Meteor server process.
>
> Many apps don't need this, though.  We're considering ways to disable it.  We also have a more efficient implementation in the hopper.

Comment: thanks. Would I be able to observe() my way around this by chance? Looking at the docs I'm wondering if there's a way to coerce it to update more frequently...

Comment: There's probably a way to force it in, but honestly I'd either (1) use `DDP` to push the data in or simply (2) wait and see what's `in the hopper` because they're on a pretty rapid release cycle...

Comment: DDP is indeed the way to go for me. I'll post a separate question on how that may look - the libraries currently out there seem very new and a bit sparse on examples. Thanks again, that should do it for me.

Comment: Got it working via your suggestions @TimDog, posted the full solution over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639700/using-node-ddp-client-to-insert-into-a-meteor-collection-from-node/14654713#14654713). Thanks a ton!